# What's the source of Gerut Lechumra and what is it

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, conversion-to-judaism, shulchan-aruch, posek-psak-decisor-ruling

BH

I heard there is a concept called Gerut Lechumra. What does this mean and what are the sources of this in Shulchan Aruch, Rambam and Gemara?

Comment: You don't need sources. if there's a doubt in the conversion if it's valid then it stands to reason it's worthwhile to do it again, to remove all doubts. That's called gerut lechumra

Comment: @robev Or if there's a doubt as to whether someone needs to convert in the first place